# How to get the url of a file field of a given node?

Tags: 8, nodes, files

`$node->field_file` gives me a [FileFieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!FileFieldItemList.php/class/FileFieldItemList/8.2.x) while the first entry seems to be a [FileItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!FileItem.php/class/FileItem/8.2.x).

`$node->field_file->getValue()` gives me an integer (I guess the file id). How can I actually get the downloadable file uri from that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```php
// Load the file.
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
// Get the URL.
$url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')
  ->generateAbsoluteString($file->getFileUri());
```

Before Drupal 10, there was a different way of doing it using `file_create_url()`.

```php
$url = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
```

Comment: You can use File::url() to make this shorter: $imageSRC = $file->url();

Comment: `File:url()` is deprecated as of `8.7.x`.  See: https://www.drupal.org/node/3019830

Answer (score 13):

As of 9.3.0 file_create_url is deprecated and it will be removed from 10.0.0 version. The new way to do it:

```
$file_uri = $node->field_file->entity->getFileUri();
\Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateString($file_uri);
```

This service has the following functions:
`generate()`
`generateString()`
`generateAbsoluteString()`
`transformRelative()`

Comment: $file->createFileUrl() seems simplier and has the same result. It's using your given service but with the relative option - source : 
'File entities returning the URL to the physical file in File::url() is deprecated, use $file->createFileUrl() instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3019830' and File.php

Comment: Yes, now you mention it... I would not even look under the 'create' term for such function...

Answer (score 7):

It is also possible to do one-liner with magic method:

`$node->field_file->entity->getFileUri();`

Or to render as string

Option 1: `$node->field_file->entity->url();`

Option 2: `file_create_url($node->field_file->entity->getFileUri());`

Answer (score 5):

For Drupal 9.3.0+ users, as mentionned :

- `File:url()` is deprecated as of 8.7.x.
- `file_create_url()` is deprecated in drupal:9.3.0 and is removed from drupal:10.0.0

`$file->createFileUrl()` looks to be the new simplest solution.

It uses the `'file_url_generator'` service mentionned by golddragon007.

You'll find details in the File.php core's file.

Answer (score -1):

> to get the file intity

`$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);`

> to get the file url

`$url = $file->url();`

Comment: $file->url() does not work anymore since it is deprecated, as mentioned in the [function documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3Aurl/8.9.x) and on this [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3019830).